# Serialization Json mixed structure with jackson

Tags: json, parsing, jackson

Please check the sample json data:

```
String INPUT = "{\"a\":[1,2,{\"b\":true},3],\"c\":3}";
```

I would like to parse that json with jackson ObjectMapper. 
As  you can see "a" is an array holds both integer and object. How can I define that a variable in POJO using anotations? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create pojo like below, since the array holds different objects, pojo will have array list of type Object to accept every type  -

```
public class JsonInput {

            @JsonProperty("a")
            private List<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();
            @JsonProperty("c")
            private Integer c;

            public List<Object> getA() {
                return a;
            }

            public void setA(List<Object> a) {
                this.a = a;
            }

            public Integer getC() {
                return c;
            }

            public void setC(Integer c) {
                this.c = c;
            }
        }
```

**Note**: You may not have further control over the objects inside the array of json input to map it to the pojo class until it holds any specific type.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks